# Check if Django queryset is read or write

Tags: django

I have to route a django queryset to a different DB's.
is it an easy way to know if the query set is read or write method?

Comment: What do you mean? A QuerySet is for querying data from the database, it's not for writing to the database.

Comment: I think he meant for cases where you do: Model.objects.filter(...).update() or .delete()

Comment: yes, i meant for update() or delete() cases..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the answer: 
a queryset object has a property-

```
queryset._for_write
queryset._for_read
```