# Django in Queryset.create() method, what is 'self._for_write' for?

Tags: python, django

In this code below, what does the code `self._for_write` mean?

```
def create(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Create a new object with the given kwargs, saving it to the database
    and returning the created object.
    """
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
    self._for_write = True
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    return obj
```

Comment: It is using an undocumented property of QuerySet class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487291/check-if-django-queryset-is-read-or-write).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base on `django.db.models.query.QuerySet.db`

```
@property
def db(self):
    """Return the database used if this query is executed now."""
    if self._for_write:
        return self._db or router.db_for_write(self.model, **self._hints)
    return self._db or router.db_for_read(self.model, **self._hints)
```

It mean when your `QuerySet` has `self._for_write == True`, it will trigger your query using `db_for_write`. For more details, please read [Django document db_for_write](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#db_for_write)